# Is there a way in an external .py to catch data populated by a kivy button (row by row) and then get len() of that dataset as well?

Tags: python-3.x, class, kivy, instance

How do I catch tuples generated by clicks on the kivy button in file 1 and the corresponding number of rows, i.e. len(), of that number of rows in file 2? Any support out there is much, much appreciated....

View explanation below...

I created a kivy app delivering a row of tupled values every time I click my button. That works fine. Now I want to pick up, e.g. a dataset of five clicks on button, i.e. 5 rows of tuples. Below is what I did in file 1:

file 1.py:

```
kv = '''
<Launch>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size:(80,80)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            text:"..."
            on_press: root.build()

'''

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


def test(t):

    size = t

    a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    a['col1'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 50, size))
    a['col2'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 50, size))
    a['col3'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(size))

    t = a

    return t

def vars_n(self):
    a = test(t=1)
    # Define objects for dataframe and col inputs
    self.a_num = pd.DataFrame(test(1))
    self.a_limit = a[(a.col3) < 1 & (a.col3 > 0.8)]
    self.a_col1 = a['col1']
    self.a_col2 = a['col2']
    self.a_col3 = a['col3']

    cols = self.a_col1, self.a_col2, self.a_col3
    lst = []
    self.a_col1, self.a_col2, self.a_col3 = 'src', 'dest', 'col3'
    for a in range(1):
        lst.append([self.a_col1, self.a_col2, self.a_col3])
        self.a_col1, self.a_col2, self.a_col3 = \
            np.random.randint(1, 40, size=1), np.random.randint(1, 40, size=1), np.random.rand(1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)

    tuple1 = self.a_col1
    tuple2 = self.a_col2
    tuple3 = self.a_col3

    q = tuple(zip(tuple1, tuple2, tuple3))

    return q

class MyDf(App, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def test_def(self):
        msg = test(1)
        print(msg)

    def test_vars_n(self):
        msg = vars_n(test(t=1))
        print(msg)

    def length(self):
        result = len(vars_n(test(t=1)))
        print(result)

    # Define output for activation of kivy button
    def press(self, instance):
        print(vars_n(test(t=1)))

    # Define kivy button configuration
    def build(self):
        butt=Button(text="...")
        butt.bind(on_press=self.press)
        return butt

MyDf().run()
```

Result after e.g. five clicks, could generate below dataset:

```
((6, 22, 0.8525529856428397),)
((12, 7, 0.3912468711230911),)
((30, 14, 0.979806646854341),)
((21, 27, 0.618131650972481),)
((8, 20, 0.9164440407619223),)
```

So, in file 2, I'd like to pull above five lines in the dataset above and, at the same time, get the len of that dataset, i.e. 5. Tried this, but it does not seem to catch the output of file 1:

file 2.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_instance = MyDf()
    
interactions = my_instance.test_vars_n()
    
interactions = np.array(interactions)
print(len(interactions)) # testing result
```

Got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "G:\...\...\...\....\file2.py", line 38, in <module>
     print(len(interactions))
 TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

EDITING with example I was inspired by in above attempts:

File 1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def test(t):

    size = t

    a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    a['col1'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 50, size))
    a['col2'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 50, size))
    a['col3'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(size))

    t = a

    return t

class ClassTest(object):

    def test_def(self):
        msg = test(1)
        print(msg)
```

File 2:

```
from Call_an_outside_function_from_class_file_1 import ClassTest

my_new_instance = ClassTest()

ClassTest().test_def()
```

Got this result, and without using the App.get_running_app() replacement:

```
       col1       col2      col3
0        48          3  0.514489

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: A couple issues with your code. First, you are trying to capture the return from `test_vars_n()` method, but that method doesn't return anything. Second, in file 2 the code `my_instance = MyDf()` is creating a new instance of `MyDf`. That new instance is not the one created in file 1. How are you running `file 2`?

Comment: Thx, for answering - I import file 1 like from file 1 import MyDf

Comment: ...also, I am still new to classes

Comment: Try replacing `my_instance = MyDf()` with `my_instance = App.get_running_app()`.

Comment: Tried that, did not take me further....take a look at the edited question.....editing includes the example I was inspired from in the first place...

Comment: Tested your comment about the 'test_vars_n()' not producing an output. Running an instance, I get a tuple containing randomized values (as generated by test_def()..)...

Comment: I didn't say that `test_vars_n()` does not produce output. I said that it doesn't return anything. That is a big difference. You need to add a `return` statement to that method. Try adding `print(interactions)` before your call to `np.array()` to see what the method has returned.

Comment: Thx, I see what you mean, John...;o) Basically, what remains now is how to collect all the output generated from number of clicks on the kivy button....five clicks generate five tuples. Tried to find a way to use append in a function inside file 1, i.e. the class file...any suggestions?